# Finding the largest of $S_1,S_2,S_3,\cdots,S_{13}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S_n$ be the sum of the first $n$ terms of a arithmetic sequence $\{a_n\}.$ If $a_3 = 12,  S_{12} > 0$ and $S_{13} <0,$ then find the largest out of $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots, S_{13}.$

---

I first let $a$ be the first term and $d$ be the common difference. Then, I got that
\begin{align*}
S_1 &= a \\
S_2 &= 2a + d \\
S_3 &= 3a + 3d \\
S_4 &= 4a + 6d \\
S_5 &= 5a + 10d \\
S_6 &= 6a + 15d \\
S_7 &= 7a + 21d \\
S_8 &= 8a + 28d \\
S_9 &= 9a + 36d \\
S_{10} &= 10a + 45d \\
S_{11} &= 11a + 55d \\
S_{12} &= 12a + 66d \\
S_{13} &= 13a + 78d.
\end{align*}
However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry
$$S_{13}=13a_7<0 \implies a_7<0$$
$$S_{12}=12\frac{a_6+a_7}{2} >0 \implies a_6+a_7>0 \implies a_6 > -a_7>0$$

Therefore $$a_1 > a_2 > \cdots > a_6 > 0 > a_7 > \cdots > a_{13}\\
\implies S_1 < S_2 < \cdots < S_6 \text{ and } S_6 > S_7 > \cdots >S_{13}. \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

You have been given that $a_3=12$, that $S_{12}>0$ and that $S_{13}<0$. What does that tell you about $a$ and $d$? Can you express $S_n$ in terms of $a$ and $n$?

Comment: Correction, $a_3 = a + 2d = 12,$ but I think that it suggests that this is a decreasing arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @questionasker Corrected. The same idea works though; this gives you a relation between $a$ and $d$, so you can express $S_n$ in terms of $a$ and $n$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

From the given relations, it may be shown that

$$18 < a < \frac{132}{7}$$ and $$-\frac{24}{7} < d < -3$$

Observe that if $a_n = a+d(n-1) < 0$, then $S_{n-1} > S_n$

However, $S_{13} = 13a + 78d < 0 \implies a + 6d < 0 \implies a_7 < 0 \implies S_6 > S_7$

Since $d < 0$, this means $S_6 > S_7 > \ldots > S_{13}$

Can we show that $S_1 < \ldots < S_6$?

In fact, it is enough to show that $S_5 < S_6 \equiv a_6 = a + 5d > 0$

Given: $S_{12} = 12a + 66d > 0$

$\implies 2a + 11d > 0$, it follows that $2(a + 5d) > 0$ since $d < 0$

Answer (score 0):

If $a_3=12$ this means that $a+2d=12\to a = 12-2d$

Knowing that $S_{12}>0$ tells us that $12a+66d>0\to 42 d+144>0 $

and if $S_{13}<0$ we know that $13a+78d<0\to  156 + 52 d<0$

Thus we have the limitation $-\frac{24}{7}<d<-3$

Anyway the largest sum is $63$ substituting $d=-3$ in $S_6,S_7$

$$\{12-2 d,24-3 d,36-3 d,48-2 d,60,3 d+72,7 d+84,12 d+96,\\18 d+108,25 d+120,33 d+132,42 d+144,52 d+156\}$$

$$\{18,33,45,54,60,63,63,60,54,45,33,18,0\}$$